# Smoothing a $\mathcal{C}^1$-map preserving the bound on rank of derivative matrix.

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-topology, vector-analysis, approximation-theory

Let $U$ be an open subset in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $m\in\mathbb{N}$, $1\leq m<n$ and let
$$\mathcal{C}^k_{\leq m}(U,\mathbb{R}^n):=\lbrace g\in\mathcal{C}^k(U,\mathbb{R}^n)\mid\dim \operatorname{im} Df(x)\leq m\:\forall x\in U\rbrace,$$
where $\mathcal{C}^k(U,\mathbb{R}^n)$ mean $k-$times continuously differentiable mappings from U to $\mathbb{R}^n$.
Is this true that 
$$\mathcal{C}^\infty_{\leq m}(U,\mathbb{R}^n)\overset{\text{dense}}{\subset}\mathcal{C}^1_{\leq m}(U,\mathbb{R}^n)$$
with the usual $\left(\mathcal{C}^1,d(\cdot,\cdot)_{\mathcal{C}^1}\right)$ distance  $d(f,g)_{\mathcal{C}^1}=\sup\limits_{x\in U}\left|f(x)-g(x)\right|+
\sup\limits_{x\in U}\left\|Df(x)-Dg(x)\right\|$.

$|\cdot|$ is length of a vector from $\mathbb{R}^n$ and
$\|\cdot\|$ is length of vector from $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$.

Comment: Asked same question on MO
http://mathoverflow.net/q/246812/95703